# Mathematical Probability of Random Tournament Draw

Tags: probability

This question is going to make me sound like a crazy sports parent, but I'm curious about the odds of a certain situation.  Our local baseball tournament has 9 All Star teams each year.  Seeds are randomly drawn, and the teams drawn 8th and 9th have to play an extra game to get the right to play the team drawn as the 1 seed.  For the third straight year, our team has been drawn into the 8 vs. 9 game, and I'm trying to figure out the probability of that happening.

It's been a very long time since I've taken any statistics course, so my first thought is that each year there is a 2/9 chance of being drawn.  Is the solution to multiply 2/9 * 2/9 * 2/9 and come out with 8/729?  Or am I just doing this all wrong?

Comment: That looks good, assuming everything is uniformly random.